# Framer motion transition in variants does't work

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I made a modal, like this :

```
<AnimatePresence
  initial={false}
  exitBeforeEnter={true}
  onExitComplete={() => null}
>
  {openModal && <Modal openModal={openModal} handleClose={close} />}
</AnimatePresence>
```

All the routes of my project are also inside an AnimatePresence, but i don't think that my problem is here.

Here is the code of my modal component :

```
import "../../css/components/backdrop.scss";
import { useFetch } from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import Quiz from "../Quiz";
import Backdrop from "../Backdrop";
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const dropIn = {
  hidden: { y: "-100vh", opacity: 0 },
  visible: {
    y: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      duration: 0.1,
      damping: 100,
      stiffness: 500,
    },
  },
  exit: { y: "100vh", opacity: 0 },
};

export default function Modal({ handleClose, text }) {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(
    `https://localhost:8443/api/quote`,
    "GET"
  );

  const [quizId, setQuizId] = useState(0);

  if (error) {
    return <span>Oups il y a eu un problème</span>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Backdrop onClick={handleClose}>
        <motion.div
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          className="popup popup__blue"
          variants={dropIn}
          key={2}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          exit="exit"
        >
          <section>
            {!isLoading ? (
              quizId !== 0 ? (
                <Quiz data={data} quizId={quizId} />
              ) : (
                <>
                  <motion.button
                    whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                    whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                    onClick={() => setQuizId(2)}
                  >
                    Un site existant
                  </motion.button>

                  <motion.button
                    whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                    whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                    onClick={() => setQuizId(1)}
                  >
                    Un nouveau site
                  </motion.button>
                </>
              )
            ) : (
              "Loading..."
            )}
          </section>
        </motion.div>
      </Backdrop>
    </>
  );
}
```

The hidden, visible, and exit variants are working, but not the transition.

Is someone knowing this issue ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: You need to provide a unique `key` to the component that is a direct child of `AnimatePresence` so it can keep track of its presence in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to <Modal> or to <Backdrop> then ? Already tried :s

Comment: In the example you are providing, it would be to `Modal`. If the transition doesn't work, I would suggest trying to put it directly into the `motion.div`.

Comment: mhh by this way if i do : <motion.div transition={{type: "spring", stiffness: 100, duration: 5,
}}> the spring is working but not the duration, weird ^^

Comment: From the docs: `duration` and `bounce` will be overridden if `stiffness`, `damping` or `mass` are set. https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/#spring

Comment: oh okay thank you, i take for exemple this tutorial, if you want to see : https://youtu.be/SuqU904ZHA4?t=479
Maybe the duration was for a previous animation